# How to get from a logical interface to the interface of the underlying NIC a device is using, in FreeBSD?

Tags: networking, ip, freebsd, network-interface

In FreeBSD, if the interface that an IP device is on happens to be a physical NIC, then I can look up the interface for the physical NIC using `arp -a`.

But what is the easiest way to get from an IP address of a known device, to the interface is is connected on, if it's on a *bridged* or some other *logical* interface? I can get its logical interface from ARP, but then it just shows the bridge interface in ARP, not the actual external interface.

What I want to identify is the interface representing a real external NIC the IP is using, so I can connect/disconnect the correct wire, errorcheck the appropriate networking switch, or whatever. Assume no multipathing, aggregated/fallover connections, or firewall issues for simplicity, and that I can distinguish external NICs from their driver (em,re etc)

How can I get that?

Examples:

- **(Most common situation)** System has `em0`, `em1`, `em2`, `em3` and they are bridged by `bridge0` which has a designated IP address. I plug a laptop into a switch which is connected to one of `emo` - `em3`. When I use `arp -a` I get the device - but it's listed with interface `bridge0` which is logically correct but physically unhelpful.
- **(less common case)** A laptop is connected through VPN into a switch connected to a bridged if.  The actual interface listed is that of the VPN, not the bridge or the switch's NIC.
- **(Less common situation by far)** A device is misconfigured with a static IP that doesn't match the interface subnet. Perhaps it's sending and receiving broadcasts, if so we would receive those. It doesn't have an ARP entry because ARP `who-has` is sent on the interface for the expected not actual subnet. But it would respond to a packet with its static IP or an ARP `who-has` through the correct NIC.

> Note - There are also other cases (VPN etc) where there might be several layers of stacked logical interfaces until one gets to the actual physical interface being used. So the issue is generally, about detecting a device with a non-physical interface and recursing to an underlying interface that represents the physical NIC it's connected through.

Answer (score 0):

A bridged interface acts like a switch, so it uses whatever interface it needs to in order to talk to the ethernet address it wants to. So for example, if `em0` is directly connected to mac addresses `aa.bb.cc.dd.ee.ff` and `a1.bb.cc.dd.ee.ff`, while `em1` is directly connected to mac addresses `aa.cc.bb.dd.ee.ff` and `a1.cc.bb.dd.ee.ff`, you already know what interface to look for. `tcpdump` is also very useful in situations like this, if you pass it the `-e` switch it displays ethernet addresses too. The other cases can be generally addressed by looking at the routing tables and deducing from there if not the actual interface, at least the most probable one. `tcpdump` proves to be the best assistant in cases like this time and again.